# accessing directive scope variable inside the controller

Tags: angularjs, scope, controller, directive, watch

parentData is being assigned a value in the parent controller.

testDir directive is being called in the parent html.

```
<test-dir directive-data="parentData"></test-dir>
```

testDir directive:

```
app.directive('testDir', function () {
  return {
   restrict: 'E',
   scope: {
    directiveData: '='   
   },
   controller: 'myctrl',
   templateUrl: 'view/myView.html'
  };
});
```

myCtrl controller:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.newVar = $scope.directiveData;
   console.log($scope.directiveData); //printing undefined.
   console.log($scope); //prints the scope objects, directiveData is having the correct value passed from the parent controller
   console.log($scope.new); //undefined
   /* remaining code using the variable newVar */
}]);
```

myView.html

```
<div>
{{directiveData}} <!-- displaying the proper value -->
</div>
```

I am not able to access the directive scope inside controller .however, It is getting printed in the html.

but on using timeout or watch function, the scope variable is accessible in controller too.

I am assuming the controller is getting created first, later directive is coming into picture.

I don't want to using watch or timeout function to resolve this issue. Any suggests?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `myctrl` != `myCtrl`

Comment: Use the `$onInit` [Life-Cycle Hook](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks).

Answer (score -1):

Try to add bindToController and controllerAs in the directive.